# What does "Assignable" really mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

C++11 removed the requirement that the value type of all containers be CopyConstructible and Assignable (although specific operations on containers may impose these requirements). In theory, that should make it possible to define, for example, `std::deque<const Foo>`, which was not possible in C++03.

Unexpectedly, gcc 4.7.2 produced its usual vomit of incomprehensible errors [1] when I tried this, but clang at least made the error readable and clang with libc++ compiled it with no errors.

Now, when two different compilers produce different results, it always makes me wonder what the correct answer is, and so I searched out all the references I could find to const/assignable/value types/containers, etc., etc. I found almost a decade's worth of very similar questions and answers, some of them here on SO and others in the various C++ mailing lists, amongst other places, including the Gnu buganizer, all of which basically can be summarized as following dialogue.

Q: Why can't I declare `std::vector<const int>` (as a simplified example)

A: Why on earth would you want to do that? It's nonsensical.

Q: Well, it makes sense to me. Why can't I do it?

A: Because the Standard requires value types to be assignable.

Q: But I'm not planning on assigning them. I want them to be const after I've created them.

A: That's not the way it works. Next question!

with a mild dashing of:

A2: C++11 has decided to allow that. You'll just have to wait. In the meantime, rethink your ridiculous design.

These don't seem like very compelling answers, although possibly I'm biased because I fall into the category of "but it makes sense to me". In my case, I'd like to have a stack-like container in which things pushed onto the stack are immutable until they are popped, which doesn't strike me as a particularly odd thing to want to be able to express with a type system.

Anyway, I started thinking about the answer, "the standard requires all containers' value types to be assignable." And, as far as I can see, now that I found an old copy of a draft of the C++03 standard, that's true; it did.

On the other hand, the value type of `std::map` is `std::pair<const Key, T>` which doesn't look to me like it's assignable. Still, I tried again with `std::deque<std::tuple<const Foo>>`, and gcc proceeded to compile it without batting an eye. So at least I have some kind of workaround.

Then I tried printing out the value of `std::is_assignable<const Foo, const Foo>` and `std::is_assignable<std::tuple<const Foo>, const std::tuple<const Foo>>`, and it turns out that the former is reported as not assignable, as you'd expect, but the latter is reported as assignable (by both clang and gcc). Of course, it's not really assignable; attempting to compile `a = b;` is rejected by gcc with the complaint `error: assignment of read-only location` (this was just about the only error message I encountered in this quest which was actually easy to understand). However, without the attempt to do an assignment, both clang and gcc are equally happy to instantiate the `deque<const>`, and the code seems to run fine.

Now, if `std::tuple<const int>` really is assignable, then I can't complain about the inconsistency in the `C++03` standard -- and, really, who cares -- but I find it disturbing that two different standard library implementations report that a type is assignable when in fact, attempting to assign to a reference of it will lead to a (very sensible) compiler error. I might at some point want to use the test in a template SFINAE, and based on what I saw today, it doesn't look very reliable.

So is there anyone who can shed some light on the question (in the title): *What does Assignable really mean?* And two bonus questions:

1) Did the committee really mean to allow instantiating containers with `const` value types, or did they have some other non-assignable case in mind?, and

2) Is there really a significant difference between the constnesses of `const Foo` and `std::tuple<const Foo>`?

---

[1] For the truly curious, here's the error message produced by gcc when trying to compile the declaration of `std::deque<const std::string>` (with a few line-endings added, and an explanation if you scroll down far enough):

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/./bits/c++allocator.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/random:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63,
                 from const_stack.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<const std::basic_string<char> >’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/allocator.h:89:11:   required from ‘class std::allocator<const std::basic_string<char> >’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_deque.h:489:61:   required from ‘class std::_Deque_base<const std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<const std::basic_string<char> > >’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_deque.h:728:11:   required from ‘class std::deque<const std::basic_string<char> >’
const_stack.cc:112:27:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:83:7:
  error: ‘const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::address(
  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::const_reference) const [
  with _Tp = const std::basic_string<char>;
  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::const_pointer =
    const std::basic_string<char>*;
  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::const_reference =
    const std::basic_string<char>&]’ cannot be overloaded
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:79:7:
  error: with ‘_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::address(
  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::reference) const [
  with _Tp = const std::basic_string<char>;
  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::pointer = const std::basic_string<char>*;
  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::reference = const std::basic_string<char>&]’
```

So what's going on here is that the standard (§ 20.6.9.1) insists that the default allocator have member functions:

```
pointer address(reference x) const noexcept;
const_pointer address(const_reference x) const noexcept;
```

but if you instantiate it with a `const` template argument (which is apparently UB), then `reference` and `const_reference` are the same type, and so the declarations are duplicated. (The body of the definition is identical, for what it's worth.) Consequently, no allocator-aware container can deal with an explicitly `const` value type. Hiding the `const` inside a `tuple` allows the allocator to instantiate. This allocator requirement from the standard was used to justify closing at least a couple of old libstdc++ bugs about problems with  `std::vector<const int>`, although it doesn't strike me as a solid point of principle. Also libc++ works around the problem in the obvious simple way, which is to provide a specialization of `allocator<const T>` with the duplicate function declarations removed.

Comment: IIRC the Assignable requirement isn't removed, it's split into two (for copies and for moves)

Comment: Haven't your already worked out that the problem isn't the requirements imposed by `std::deque` (or sequence containers in general), but by `std::allocator`? Rather than _what does assignable mean_, shouldn't your question be _is it ok to use an allocator that works with `const` types_ (bearing in mind that `std::allocator` does not work with `const` types)?

Comment: @BenVoigt: it's really gone. It used to be 23.1(3): "The type of objects stored in these components must meet the requirements of CopyConstructible types (20.1.3), and the additional requirements of Assignable types". That paragraph, the next one, and the associated table 64, (referring to Assignable) are all gone. The remaining requirement is that if you use a copy constructor or copy assignment on the container, then the value type T must be CopyInsertable into the container type X.

Comment: @jogojapan: I know that it's ok to use an allocator that works with const types, if that's what I want to do. I don't know how to detect if a T is assignable, which I might want to know to implement a container, because it is always possible to avoid assign. For example you can do swap with just copy constructs and destructs, a mechanism perfectly compatible with const types, or aggregates with const members. So my question is what it is.

Comment: @BenVoigt, also you are right that Assignable was split. But the more important part is that the requirements no longer apply to the container type; they now apply to specific operations. If you do an element assign, the value type needs to be CopyAssignable. But you're now free to create a container from a non-assignable value type, provided you never try to assign elements, or rearrange them. Adding new elements, for example, is fine.

Comment: I am sorry if I still misunderstand your question, but if it's about how to detect whether something is assignable, would `std::is_assignable` (and related, see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable) be the answer? Those can be combined with `std::enable_if` to implement a templated container class.

Comment: @jogojapan: did you read all those words I wrote? I tried that, and it reported that `std::tuple<const int>` is assignable (although `const int` isn't). Hence the question. (Both gcc and clang reported the same results.)

Comment: Of course `const int` isn't assignable. If you have the right allocator, you can use it in a vector, but only for operations that don't require assignability (e.g. `emplace_back` would be ok).

Comment: @jogojapan: I know that. But why is std::tuple<const int> assignable? How would you assign to it?

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Good question (+1). Personally, I think it would help reducing the post to just a question about `std::is_assignable` applied to `const int` vs. `tuple<const int>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++03, `Assignable` was defined by table 64 in §23.1/4,

```
    Expression    Return type    Post-condition
    t = u         T&             t is equivalent to u
```

On the one hand this requirement was not met for `std::map`. On the other hand it was too strict a requirement for `std::list`. And C++11 demonstrated that it's not even necessary for `std::vector`, in general, but is imposed by use of certain operations (such as assignment).

In C++11 the corresponding requirement is named `CopyAssignable` and is defined by table 23 in §17.6.3.1/2,

```
    Expression    Return type    Return value    Post-condition
    t = v         T&             t               t is equivalent to v, the
                                                 value of v is unchanged
```

The main differences are that container elements no longer need to be `CopyAssignable`, and that there's a corresponding requirement `MoveAssignable`.

Anyway, a structure with a `const` data member is clearly not assignable unless one chooses to read “equivalent to” with a very peculiar interpretation.

The only operation-independent element type requirement in C++11 is, as far as I can see (from table 96 in §23.2.1/4) that it must be `Destructible`.

---

Regarding `std::is_assignable`, it does not quite test the `CopyAssignable` criterion.

Here’s what `std::is_assignable<T, U>` implies, according to table 49 in C++11 §20.9.4.3/3:

> “The expression
>   `declval<T>() = declval<U>()` is
>   well-formed when treated
>   as an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5). Access
>   checking is performed as if
>   in a context unrelated to `T`
>   and `U`. Only the validity of
>   the immediate context of
>   the assignment expression
>   is considered. [*Note:* The
>   compilation of the
>   expression can result in
>   side effects such as the
>   instantiation of class
>   template specializations
>   and function template
>   specializations, the
>   generation of
>   implicitly-defined
>   functions, and so on. Such
>   side effects are not in the
>   “immediate context” and
>   can result in the program
>   being ill-formed. *—end
>   note* ]”

Essentially this implies an access/existence + argument type compatibility check of `operator=`, and nothing more.

However, Visual C++ 11.0 doesn't appear to do the access check, while g++ 4.7.1 chokes on it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

struct A {};
struct B { private: B& operator=( B const& ); };

template< class Type >
bool isAssignable() { return is_assignable< Type, Type >::value;  }

int main()
{
    wcout << boolalpha;
    wcout << isAssignable< A >() << endl;              // OK.
    wcout << isAssignable< B >() << endl;              // Uh oh.
}
```

Building with Visual C++ 11.0:

```
[D:\dev\test\so\assignable]
> cl assignable.cpp
assignable.cpp

[D:\dev\test\so\assignable]
> _
```

Building with g++ 4.7.1:

```
[D:\dev\test\so\assignable]
> g++ assignable.cpp
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits: In substitution of 'template static decltype (((declval)()=(declval)(), std::__sfinae_types::__one()))std::__is_assignable_helper::__test(int) [with _
Tp1 = _Tp1; _Up1 = _Up1; _Tp = B; _Up = B] [with _Tp1 = B; _Up1 = B]':
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits:1055:68:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__is_assignable_helper::value'
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits:1060:12:   required from 'struct std::is_assignable'
assignable.cpp:10:59:   required from 'bool isAssignable() [with Type = B]'
assignable.cpp:16:32:   required from here
assignable.cpp:7:24: error: 'B& B::operator=(const B&)' is private
In file included from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_pair.h:61,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:65,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/ios:41,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/ostream:40,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/iostream:40,
                 from assignable.cpp:1:
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits:1049:2: error: within this context
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits: In substitution of 'template static decltype (((declval)()=(declval)(), std::__sfinae_types::__one())) std::__is_assignable_helper::__test(int) [with _
Tp1 = _Tp1; _Up1 = _Up1; _Tp = B; _Up = B] [with _Tp1 = B; _Up1 = B]':
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits:1055:68:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__is_assignable_helper::value'
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits:1060:12:   required from 'struct std::is_assignable'
assignable.cpp:10:59:   required from 'bool isAssignable() [with Type = B]'
assignable.cpp:16:32:   required from here
assignable.cpp:7:24: error: 'B& B::operator=(const B&)' is private
In file included from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_pair.h:61,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:65,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/ios:41,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/ostream:40,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/iostream:40,
                 from assignable.cpp:1:
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits:1049:2: error: within this context
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::__is_assignable_helper::value':
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits:1060:12:   required from 'struct std::is_assignable'
assignable.cpp:10:59:   required from 'bool isAssignable() [with Type = B]'
assignable.cpp:16:32:   required from here
assignable.cpp:7:24: error: 'B& B::operator=(const B&)' is private
In file included from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_pair.h:61,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:65,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/ios:41,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/ostream:40,
                 from d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/iostream:40,
                 from assignable.cpp:1:
d:\bin\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/type_traits:1055:68: error: within this context

[D:\dev\test\so\assignable]
> _
```

So, summing up, the standard's `std::is_assignable` appears to be of very limited utility, and as of this writing it can't be relied on for portable code.

---

**EDIT:** Replaced `<utility>` with correct `<type_traits`. Interestingly it didn't matter for g++. Not even for the error message, so I just let that be as it was.

Comment: Just to be clear, then, you'd agree that bugs should be filed against both mentioned standard libraries?

Comment: @rici: no, not for the reason of reporting `true` for the tuple, because while it is clearly not `CopyAssignable`, it appears to fulfil the requirements of `std::is_assignable`. See the second section of my answer (I just added that). However, at least *some* implementation is buggy, since they don't agree!

Comment: FWIW your program is accepted with a snapshot of upcoming GCC 4.8, yielding expected results (i.e. outputting 'true' then 'false').

Comment: Either you copy-pasted the command wrong, or you forgot to turn on C++11 for `g++`.

Comment: @rubenvb: it's [stl's mingw-build with c++11 support as default](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html). anyway the command just invokes a batch file, and that batch file could have supplied any options. as it is, though, it just ensures that that the mingw\bin directory is in front of PATH, because g++ has some trouble with something (i don't recall what) being picked up elsewhere. so there are two layers of "indirection" here, and a third one could have been command interpreter alias, in windows via `doskey`. but no such involved, happily. :-)

Comment: FYI, your example program works fine with clang (3.3), too. libc++ actually *uses* is_assignable in one header file (memory) but more interestingly it has a test suite which reminded me that you should be checking is_assignable<A&,... since is_assignable<int, int> will/should return false. That doesn't change any of your examples, though.

Comment: +1 and I added a bunch more explanatory material in a separate answer. As you say, hth and thanks.

Comment: Isn't `declval<T>() = declval<U>()` doing a move-assignment check anyway, since the right-hand-side is a temporary? (is that an *xvalue*?)

Comment: @BenVoigt, it depends on what U is. `std::is_move_assignable<T>` is defined as `std::is_assignable<T&, T&&>` while `std::is_copy_assignable<T>` is `is_assignable<T&,
const T&>`

Answer (score 4):

I'm giving this to [Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) but I wanted to add a couple of notes for future reference.

As Alf says, `std::is_*_assignable` really only check for the existence (explicit or implicit) of an appropriate assignment operator. They don't necessarily check to see whether it will be well-formed if instantiated. This works fine for the default assignment operators. If there is a member declared `const`, the default assignment operators will be deleted. If a base class has a deleted assignment operator, the default assignment operator will be deleted. So if you just let the defaults do their thing, it should be fine.

However, if you do declare `operator=`, it becomes your responsibility (if you care) to ensure that it is appropriately deleted. For example, this will compile and run (at least with clang), and reports that `C` is_assignable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

struct A { const int x; A() : x() {}};

struct C { 
  struct A a;
  C& operator=( C const& other);
};

template< class Type >
bool isAssignable() { return is_assignable< Type&, const Type& >::value;  }

int main()
{
    wcout << boolalpha;
    wcout << isAssignable< A >() << endl; // false
    wcout << isAssignable< C >() << endl; // true
    C c1;
    C c2;
}
```

The absence of the assignment operator's definition isn't noted until link-time, and in this case not at all because the assignment operator is never used. But note that a use of `C::operator=` contingent on `std::is_assignable` would be allowed to compile. Of course, I couldn't have defined `C::operator=` in a way that resulted in assigning to its member `a`, because that member isn't assignable.

That's not a particularly interesting example though. What get's interesting is the use of templates, such as the `std::tuple` issue which started this whole question. Let's add a couple of templates into the above, and actually define `C::operator=` through assignment to its member `a`:

```
using namespace std;

template<bool> struct A {
  A() : x() {}
  const int x;
};

template<bool B> struct C {
  struct A<B> a;
  C& operator=( C const& other) {
    this->a = other.a;
    return *this;
  }
};  

template< class Type >
bool isAssignable() { return is_assignable< Type&, const Type& >::value;  }

int main()
{   
    wcout << boolalpha;
    wcout << isAssignable< A<false> >() << endl; // false
    wcout << isAssignable< C<false> >() << endl; // true
    C<false> c1;
    C<false> c2;
    c1 = c2;                                     // Bang
    return 0;
}
```

Without the assignment at the end, the code compiles and runs (under clang 3.3) and reports that `A<false>` is not assignable (correct) but that `C<false>` is assignable (surprise!).  The actual attempt to use `C::operator=` reveals the truth, because it is not until that point that the compiler attempts to actually instantiate that operator. Up to then, and through the instantiations of `is_assignable`, the operator was just a declaration of a public interface, which is -- as Alf says -- all that `std::is_assignable` is really looking for.

Phew.

So bottom line, I think this is a deficiency in both the standard and the standard library  implementations with respect to standard aggregate objects whose `operator=` should be deleted if any of the component types is not assignable. For `std::tuple`, § 20.4.2.2 lists as requirements for `operator=` that all component types be assignable, and there ae similar requirements for other types, but I don't think that requirement requires library implementors to delete inapplicable `operator=`.

But, then, as far as I can see, nothing stops library implementations from doing the deletion (except the annoyance factor of conditionally deleting assignment operators). In my opinion after obsessing about this for a couple of days, they should do so, and furthermore the standard should require them to do so. Otherwise, reliable use of `is_assignable` impossible.

Comment: @LucDanton: but in the case of `std::tuple<const int>`, the assignment operator does not make sense. I think that `std::tuple` should explicitly delete it. In that case, `std::is_assignable<std::tuple<const int>>` would be `false_type` which is surely the point of `is_assignable`, as well as satisfying POLS. If all templated objects whose assignability is contingent on the assignability of (some) template arguments were to delete the assignment operator in the case that the relevant template arguments were not assignable, then the whole apparatus would work correctly.

Comment: @LucDanton, the margins are too small :). If I intend to test template parameters for assignability, it will work fine as long as everyone else does too. I can't just do it myself. Furthermore, if I correctly delete the assignment operator for unassignable instantiations, then the client will get an easy-to-understand error message (assignment operator deleted), rather than having to trace back through pages of template instantiation traceback.

Comment: A pragmatical consideration as to why tuples aren't mandated to conditionally provide assignment operators is that it's more annoying to provide than usual (partial specializations instead of the more straightforward kind of SFINAE). In any case, with regards to the present situation, I wouldn't blame the implementations, but the requirements.

Comment: @LucDanton, I think I phrased that paragraph in my answer very badly. We probably agreed with each other all along. Sorry for the confusion. I edited the paragraph.